# How to maintain nested parallel connections to MySQL from Python

Tags: python, pymysql

We have a small python program that sorts files from a directory that is constantly being filled and loads it into the right MySQL table accordingly.

There are seven tables, and to each one the python program maintains 5 open connections (using a tool called DBUtils.PooledDB).

I want to send files through all 35(7x5) connections in parallel, but while python multiprocessing using map enables me to do so at one level (the five connections to one table), the parent process has to run in serial (going through the seven tables).

I use multiprocessing.Pool.map_async() to start the whole process, so all 35 connections are active at the start, but as each table finishes off the rest of the tables have to wait for the entire pool to finish.

I want to be able to run all 35 processes separately so they can continue to work independent of each other.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pymysql
from DBUtils.PooledDB import PooledDB

# Pool of 35 connections
g_pool_0 = PooledDB(creator=pymysql, maxconnections=5 host=host, user=user db=db)
...
g_pool_6 = PooledDB(creator=pymysql, maxconnections=5 host=host, user=user db=db)

def insert_to_db(filename):
    # Load filename data into the database according to the filename

if __name__ == "__main__":

    while True:

        files_0 = glob.glob(join(cur_d, 'results/*_0.csv'))
        ...
        files_0 = glob.glob(join(cur_d, 'results/*_6.csv'))

        # start inserting to DB on all 7 databases

        pool_0 = Pool(5)
        pool_0.map_async(insert_to_db, files_0)
        ...
        pool_7 = Pool(5)
        pool_7.map_async(insert_to_db, files_7)

        pool_0.close()
        pool_0.join()
        ...
        pool_7.close()
        pool_7.join()
```

This works, but I have to use a while loop to continue processing the directory that's receiving a constant stream of files. If there are any active connections in the while loop the others have to wait for the while loop to finish.

I don't want to run 7 seperate scripts. Is there anyway to do this in a nested threads/processes?